# Botones para BOT de Telegram (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, telegram, telegram-bot

Estoy desarrollando un bot de Telegram en Java Script.
El problema que tengo es con los botones. Quiero que aparezcan en diferentes filas, según como yo quiera, pero no consigo "ordenarlos".

Os pongo el código que tengo:

```
bot.command('rrss',(ctx)=>{
    var chatId = ctx.chat.id;
    var botones = {
        reply_markup:{
            inline_keyboard:[
             [{text:"Web��", url:"https://forocoches.com"},
             {text:"Twitter��️", url:"https://twitter.com/"},
             {text:"Instagram��", url:"https://www.instagram.com//"},
             {text:"Facebook��", url:"https://www.facebook.com//"},
             {text:"YouTube��", url:"https://www.youtube.com/"},
             {text:"Twitch��", url:"https://www.twitch.tv/"}
         ]
            ]
        },
        parse_mode:"HTML",
    };

    
    bot.telegram.sendMessage(chatId, "<b><i>Estas son las redes sociales:</i></b>", botones);

})
```

De esta forma, me aparecen todos en una línea, tal que así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y yo quiero algo así (más limpio):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un saludo y gracias de antebrazo.

Answer (score 0):

Debes poner cada boton dentro de un corchete:

```
[{text:'',url:' '}],
[{text:' ',url:' '}],
// ....etc.
```